# ios make navigation bar clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, touches

Just trying to make the navigationBar of my navigationController clickable.
It works well with

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* tapRecon = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(toggleMenu)];
tapRecon.delegate = self;
tapRecon.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.navigationBar addGestureRecognizer:tapRecon];
```

but when I have a back button, impossible to click on it (the gesture might take over the button).

So, I tried something found here :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return (![[[touch view] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UIButton class]]);
}
```

And nothing, because `[touch view]` is alway UINavigationBar...

Last thing i tried to do is setting the `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO`. It's ok, we can click on the back button, but the `toggleMenu` action of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` is still called.

Do you have an idea to make the back button works again, but not calling `toggleMenu` at the same time ?

Thanks !

## EDIT :

Juste found how to do :

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    for (UIView* sub in self.navigationBar.subviews) {
        NSString *cl = NSStringFromClass([sub class]);
        if ([cl isEqualToString:@"UINavigationItemButtonView"]) {
            CGRect bback = sub.frame;
            CGPoint pointInView = [touch locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
            return !CGRectContainsPoint(bback, pointInView);
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: The back button is an instance of UIBarButtonItem which is NOT an UIView subclass. Apple uses some private class for displaying these buttons and that should be the reason why your check for the touch view is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can make a button that surrounds the nav bar, and make another button for pressing back. Be sure to arrange it on top of the nav bar button in IB

Comment: I'm not using IB. Do you think by creating my own buttons, I can fetch them with shouldReceiveTouches ?

Answer (score -2):

This is a solution for Swift code:

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    for view in self.navigationBar.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            if touch.view.isEqual(button) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Just put this in your delegate for your `UIGestureRecognizer`.

Comment: Not sure why I'm getting downvoted on this. The code works and there's no accepted solution (even though the asker posted one in his question).